# Set location of SQL Server Compact database on publish

Tags: sql-server-ce, publishing, local-database

I have a Winforms application that uses a SQL Server Compact `.SDF` database to store data. The application runs fine in Visual Studio when debugging, though when I use the "Publish" option of my project and run the program after installation, I always get an error saying "The database file cannot be found".

I set the connection string as follows

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Cellar.sdf");
connString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", fileName);
```

The database `Cellar.sdf` is inside my program folder.

[image]

It is obvious that the path to the database is wrong, but is there a way for me to set the path where I want my application to be installed when using the "Publish" function, or some way to find out where the database file gets copied? What is the proper approach to include a local database file in a desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the DataDirectory macro, and set the location to an suitable place in code.

```
connString = string.Format("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\{0};", fileName);

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is our connection string: Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Chinook40.sdf
        // Set the data directory to the users %AppData% folder
        // So the Chinook40.sdf file must be placed in:  C:\\Users\\<Username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
    }
```

This will require you to copy the database file to the desird location (if it does not exist already) during initial application launch.

Comment: I can run a line of code to check if it already exists, or otherwise copy it there, though, how am I to copy it? I know the destination, but how can I figure out where it's being deployed on installation? If I could set that location right away, I wouldn't need to copy it. A lot of work when it should be possible to just select a location to place it in my opinion.

Comment: If you do not require the database to survive app updates, simply use DataDirectory with no code

Comment: I ended up doing this,
`string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory, "Cellar.sdf");
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            connString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", fileName);`

Though I'd consider your solution as a more proper way to do it!